# javascript - disable popup preview on html input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Browsers usually keep track of texts entered in html input fields. Is there any way to disable popup preview on texts fields via javascript or jquery?

[image]

Comment: Repeated question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: Do some googling before posting questions here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one:

```
 <input type="textbox" autocomplete="off" />
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

using javascript :

```
yourInput.setAttribute( "autocomplete", "off" );
```

jQuery

```
$("input").attr("autocomplete", "off");
```